# Postgresql replication without DELETE statement

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

We have a requirement that says we should have a copy of all the items that were in our system at one point. The most simple way to explain it would be replication but ignoring the delete statement (INSERT and UPDATE are ok)
Is this possible ? or maybe the better question would be what is the best approach to tackle this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy/replica of current database and use  triggers via dblink from current database to the replica. Use after insert and after update trigger to insert and update data in replica.

So whenever a row insertion/updation take place in current database it will directly reflect to replica.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand the question completely, but I'll try to help:

- First (opposite to @Sunit) - I suggest avoiding triggers. Triggers are introducing additional overhead and impacting performance.
- The solution I would use (and I'm actually using in few of my projects with similar demands) - don't use DELETE at all. Instead you can add bit (boolean) column called "Deleted", set its default value to 0 (false), and instead of deleting the row you update this field to 1 (true). You'll also need to change your other queries (SELECT) to include something like "WHERE Deleted = 0".
- Another option is to continue using DELETE as usual, and to allow deleting records from both primary and replica, but configure WAL archiving, and store WAL archives in some shared directory. This will allow you to moment-in-time recovery, meaning that you'll be able to restore another PostgreSQL instance to state of your cluster in any moment in time (i.e. before the deletion). This way you'll have a trace of deleted records, but pretty complicated procedure to reach the records. Depending on how often deleted records will be checked in the future (maybe they are not checked at all, but simply kept for just-in-case tracking) this approach my also help.